# Why are my desktop files and folders duplicated or showing 2 times?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, duplicate-files

Files on my Desktop are showing **2 times**.

Whenever I'm adding a new file or folder, it's showing 2 times, OR copying file from any SSD or HDD to desktop, it's automatically showing double.

Please refer to the screenshot to check the original issue,

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Check your Gnome Shell extensions. First install `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` if you do not have it already. Find and launch it by typing `Extensions` in the Applications overview. Disable your extensions one by one to check which one is causing the issue.

I suspect you may have two extensions active that manage the desktop, e.g. the default Desktop icons and Desktop Icons NG.